# Overriding Panels' default category structure

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

The development house I work at uses Panels for stuff a lot, and they're a central design tool for our clients. While we're able to group our own Panels content types and View Panes by specifying a category name, it isn't so easy for everything else: there's the useless content types in the "Activity" category, the confusing content types in "Entity", the overwhelming and mostly-useless content types in "Node (Tokens)", the *really* useless content types in "Page elements" (Why would I need to repeat design elements already in place on the page?)... I could go on.

Plus random blocks are always dropped in the "Miscellaneous" category -- seemingly the last place I always look for content types I cannot find.

What I really need is the ability to organize Panels content types, and hide categories that aren't needed.

To that end I've started work on a module that lets the use build and organize Panels content types into custom categories. However, the first major roadblock I've run into is convincing Panels to use my layout instead of the one it generates from the plugin info hooks.

In panels/includes/add-content.inc is `template_preprocess_panels_add_content_modal()`, which is where Panels seems to set up its category tree (Via the function's $vars argument).

1. Is there any way of inserting a hook into the function chain that
   discards the $var variable that Panels is passing to
   `template_preprocess_panels_add_content_modal()` and instead
   delivers my own?
2. If not, is there a way to override `template_preprocess_panels_add_content_modal()` with my own
   version?
3. Or, best yet, is there a module somewhere that already does what I'm trying to do?

Many thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, you already know how to do hook_ctools_block_info, etc, for your organizing your custom stuff.  You just want to organize the builtins?

Comment: @MPD -- That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Whaddayamean you can override functions starting with **'template'** like you can functions starting with **'hook'**?"* I ask...

I've finished my organizer and will post it as a sandbox module if my boss lets me. I ultimately just copied the source of `template_preprocess_panels_add_content_modal()` from `panels/includes/add-content.inc` and changed what was passed on -- `$vars['categories']`, `$vars['categories_array']` and `$vars['root_content']` were particularly important.

Surprised nobody answered this -- would've been an easy 10 points to just say "Yeah, template_preprocess functions work a bit like hooks in that you can insert your own version higher up the chain just by naming it a certain way..."